# Send empty userform to a user and return it filled in

Tags: html, vba, forms, outlook

There is probably a much better way to do this but I don't know Outlook that well. I want to send a form to some users where they have to tick some boxes, provide some information and then return this.

I thought about sending a mail containing the userform they could fill in and then return it filled in to me.

To make it clearer, this form will be sent to a car dealer from my company among the world everytime we request some parts back. So in the userform I Send him will be mentioned the parts required and other info -> which makes it unique and not a survey and then he will fill in the rest of the information in the userform (which are the specifications of those parts) before resending it to me.

Any ideas or better suggestions ?

Comment: cant you just create a userform like structure manually from shapes on a excel file and link it.... so that the user can enter the details and the data gets updated in the hidden data sheets....

Comment: This could work yes, but I'd like to avoid attaching an excel file to the mail to keep is simpler. I have already made some great Outlook mail templates combining html and vba but it was only to display information and not to collect something in return. I'll keep your suggestion in mind though

Comment: You can get the values entered store them in variables...Create another mail object paste the values of the variables in the body of the mail and send it back to you from the vba

Answer (score 1):

Can't do that. Outlook does not process HTML forms or run scripts in emails.

You will need to design some other way of collecting the data.

Comment: Yes, I just looked for more information and apparently the possibility depends on the client : [https://www.sitepoint.com/forms-in-email/]. I think I will give this one up and just ask them to reply to my mail with the information. The issue with that is that I can't verify their input before they actually send the mail. I'm open to any suggestions

Comment: You can send a message with a table and ask them to fill out the table cells in your original message when replying. You can then process the reply and extract the data from the HTML body.

Comment: Yes sure, but in that case I can't verify the format of the information they provide. There is a field which is required and if they didn't tick it then I'll have to chase them to make sure they do (the idea of sending a form was to actually prevent them from replying to me without ticking this field)

Comment: Looks like having a web based solution is your best bet.